# Bitnami Cassandra external loadbalance ip for each pod

Tags: cassandra, bitnami

How do I add external IP's to all pods in bitnami cassandra helm chart. I don't want to use nodeport as i might have 10+ k8 nodes.
Or single load balancer ip [loadBalancerIP:""]is only option available?